# Add-on Aero Bars to an Already Aero Handlebar

Tags: road-bike, aero-bars

I've recently upgraded from a Specialized Allez to a ([3T Strada Pro Force](https://us.3t.bike/en/219-strada#/271-bikes_size-m/305-type-complete_bike/306-level-pro_force)).  I took it on its first long ride (56 miles) and my, already bad, wrists really suffered.  I changed hand positions as often as I could, but it was still an uncomfortable ride.  On my Allez, I have a set of Profile Airstryke aero bars which have been great because being in an aero position takes the pressure off my wrists.

The 3T Strada Pro comes with [Aeronova Aero Handlebars](https://us.3t.bike/en/products/dropbars/aeronova-561.html).  With them having a flatter shape, I'm not sure if there are any add-on aero bars, like the Airstrykes, that can attach to this handlebar.

Although I enjoy riding in the aero position, I do it more for comfort and hand position options than I do for aerodynamics.  Are there any add-on aero bars that I can purchase that will fit this type of handlebar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most clip-on aero bars attach near the stem, where the handle bars have a round profile, not where the bars have a flat profile. The elbow pads are outboard of the mounting point, which will put them over the flat portion of the bars.

As an aside I would try to assess why you are experiencing wrist issues.  You may simply need adjust your setup. It is also possible that on the new bars you are twisting wrists. Ideally you want to keep your wrists straight as possible. You may need to adjust the position of shifter/brake on the bars to help facilitate.

Comment: Thanks!  My handlebars do indeed have about 1.5-2" of round profile near the stem.  My only experience with aerobars is the AirStrykes.  I found that diamond shape near the end allowed for a few more hand position options, especially on trainer rides.  In regards to the wrist pain, it is mostly due to an overuse injury from my last job where the ligaments became stretched out.  Also looking at a wrist/forearm strengthening routine to see if that can help.

Answer (score 1):

My cheap (heavy aluminium) ones would clamp securely to a flattened bar, so it's certainly possible. Look for a pair of screws fore and aft of the handlebar, rather than a screw and hinge. Where they probably wouldn't clamp securely is on the transitional section between a circular clamping region and a flattened top; while this is small on the bars linked in the Q, it may well be exactly where you want to clamp as there doesn't look to be much room between the stem and the flattened part, but mounting the aero bars on the flattened part is likely to leave them too wide.

The Airstrykes, in common with others where the aero bars join at the front, fix the separation between the clamping points, which means more luck is needed.